# Unknow symbol in while loop of java

Tags: java

I am reading some codes and I saw someone wrote `while (T-->0)`

I dont know what that means, I mean what the symbol `-->` stand for. I am just beginner ,so sorry if my question is stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--` decrement what's on left

`>` greater than

for example:

`int i = 4;`

`i-- > 4; //evaluates to false because i is 3 after --`

EDIT: As one of the commenters pointed out this actually first compares and THEN decrements, so the line of code above will evaluate to `4 > 4` and straight after that i becomes 3. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: Actually i-- is evaluated after the test. The result would still be false though, because 4 is not greater than 4.

Answer (score 2):

Basically to simplify, its equivalent to:

```
while (T>0) {
   T=T-1;
   //blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the integer(?) T is reduced by 1 on each cycle and the while loop body is run until T becomes equal to 0.
In my opinion the code is not using best practices of formatting, it should be written

```
while (T-- > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it tests if `T` is greater than 0 then decrements `T` by 1 unit.

Answer (score 0):

-- decrement operator. Here T is compared first and value decremented.

> greater than operator